# Blowing up of the curve $x^4+y^4-xyz^2$ in $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, blowup

[Problem] (Fulton's Algebraic curves Problems 7.9)

Let $C=V(x^4+y^4-xyz^2)$. Write down equations for a nonsingular curve $X$ in some $\mathbb{P}^N$ that is birationally equivalent to $C$. (Use the Segre imbedding)

---

[My attempt]

First, I found the multiple points (singular points) by using gradient.
The only singular point is $P=[0:0:1]$.

Next, I tried to blow up this curve by considering $[x:y:z] \times [u:t] \in \mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1$ $$ \begin{cases} x^4+y^4-xyz^2=0 \\xt-yu=0  \end{cases}$$

Then by multiplying $u^4$ to the first equation, we obtain $x^4u^4+y^4u^4-xyz^2u^4= x^4u^4+(xt)^4-xz^2u^3(xt)=x^2(x^2u^4+x^2t^4-z^2u^3t) =0$

Therefore this $x^2u^4+x^2t^4-z^2u^3t=0$ is the first result of blowing up of the curve.

However, at $[x:y:z] \times [u:t]=[0:0:1] \times [0:1]$ , by observing affine case ($z=1, t=1$), $x^2u^4+x^2+u^3=0$ have singularity.

I'm stuck here. I don't know how can I proceed the blowing up this curve one more time and how to use the Segre imbedding..

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: You have a curve in $\Bbb P^2\times\Bbb P^1$. Use the Segre embedding to put this in to $\Bbb P^5$ so you have a curve in $\Bbb P^5$. Blow up again.

Comment: @KReiser . For using segre embedding, I think we need $(k,k)$ bi-degree curve. For example, $(2,2)$ bi-degree, $x_1^2y_1^2$ can be $T_{1,1}^2$ but $x_1^2y_1^4$ can't be written by $T_{1,1}, \ldots, T_{m,n}$ ,where $T_{i,j}$ ~ $x_iy_j$.

Comment: However, I know that by multiplying all $x_1^j, \ldots , x_m^j$ it is possible but very complicated. For example, $V(x_1y_1^3) = V(x_1^3y_1^3,x_2^2x_1y_1^3,x_3^2x_1y_1^3) $ (by multiplying $x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$ and $x_1^3y_1^3,x_2^2x_1y_1^3,x_3^2x_1y_1^3$ can be written $T_{i,j}$ terms but now there are three equations so very hard to blow up.. Is there another idea? The Fulton's book covers only blowing up in $\mathbb{P}^2$. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I find a tiny but nice trick in this situation.

The curve $ x^2u^4+x^2t^4-z^2u^3t=0$ have an open subset $x^2u^4+x^2t^4-z^2u^3t=0 , u \neq 0$.

These two varieties are obviously birationally equivalent since it is just an open dense subset.

Now,
$$ x^2u^4+x^2t^4-z^2u^3t=0 , u \neq 0 $$
$$ \Rightarrow x^2u^2+\frac{x^2t^4}{u^2}-z^2ut=0  \Leftrightarrow x^2u^2+y^2t^2-z^2ut=0$$
(in the last part, use $xt=yu$)

Therefore, we find the blowing up $x^2u^2+y^2t^2-z^2ut=0$ which has $(2,2)$ bi-degree.

Finally, we can use Segre embedding and the answer is $T_{1,1}^2+T_{2,2}^2-T_{3,1}T_{3,2}=0$ in $\mathbb{P^5}$.